# Enable/Disable Javascript based on screen size

Tags: javascript, jquery, responsive-design

I am creating a responsive site where I am using a slide out panel to diaplay content on the desktop version.

For my tab/mob site I would not be using this, because it will look weird along with the responsive mobile navigation.

I would like to find a way to enable/disable this slide out JS, without realoding the site.

I have been looking at the following posts, but these all requires that I reload the page, none of them allow me to enable/disable the JS only based on screen re-size.

[how to disable javascript for responsive design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13234894/how-to-disable-javascript-for-responsive-design)

[disabling javascript plugin based on window size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19780977/disabling-javascript-plugin-based-on-window-size)

[jQuery: Disable & Enable Plugin based on browser window size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15877286/jquery-disable-enable-plugin-based-on-browser-window-size)

Answer (score 1):

You could create a container that holds a static image as an alias of the default slider.
This container (lets say `#staticImg`) would be invisible on wide screens.

In narrower screens, hide the original div (the one that holds the slider) and show up the `#staticImg` in place of the original slider.

CSS

```css
#staticImg { display:none }

@media all and (max-width: 450px) { 
    #originalHolder { display:none }
    #staticImg { display:block }
}
```

*Javascript will still be working, but the slider will be invisible*